# Snackbar for Circular Android Wear Designs

Tags: android-layout, notifications, wear-os, snackbar

The classic Snackbar provided from Android design library works in wear project.
In square display they looks fine, but in round they don't.
The corner of the snackbar are cropped by the circular display.
Does anyone know a workaround?
I don't want to use toast.

see the image:

[image]

the code that I use:

```
Snackbar.make(view, serverMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/04/build-beautifully-for-android-wear.html), there are several ways you can do this. These are :

1. Using [BoxInsertLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/BoxInsetLayout.html) which is mentioned in the Use a [Shape-Aware Layout guide](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html?utm_campaign=android%20wear_discussion_roundscreen_042016&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#same-layout).

[image]

The `BoxInsetLayout` class included in the Wearable UI Library extends FrameLayout and lets you define a single layout that works for both square and round screens. This class applies the required window insets depending on the screen shape and lets you easily align views on the center or near the edges of the screen.

2. [WatchViewStub](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WatchViewStub.html?utm_campaign=android%20wear_discussion_roundscreen_042016&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog)

   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity_main"
    app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity_main"
    tools:context="com.android.example.watchviewstub.MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">